# Parallelize search in a Java set

Tags: java, multithreading, collections

I have a `List<String>` called `lines` and a huge (~3G) `Set<String>` called `voc`.  I need to find all lines from `lines` that are in `voc`. Can I do this multithreaded way?

Currently I have this straightforward code:

```
for(String line: lines) {
  if (voc.contains(line)) {
    // Great!!
  }
}
```

Is there a way to search for few lines at the same time? May be there are existing solutions?

PS: I am using `javolution.util.FastMap`, because it behaves better during filling up.

Comment: Currently ~50000 lines are searched in 1 second. vox is a Set, not a List.

Comment: I believe @threadswarm provides a pretty good answer. you should accept his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible implementation.  Please note that error/interruption handling has been omitted but this might give you a starting point.  I included a main method so you could copy and paste this into your IDE for a quick demo.

***Edit**: Cleaned things up a bit to improve readability and List partitioning*

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionService;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class ParallelizeListSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        List<String> searchList = new ArrayList<String>(7);
        searchList.add("hello");
        searchList.add("world");
        searchList.add("java");
        searchList.add("debian");
        searchList.add("linux");
        searchList.add("jsr-166");
        searchList.add("stack");

        Set<String> targetSet = new HashSet<String>(searchList);

        Set<String> matchSet = findMatches(searchList, targetSet);
        System.out.println("Found " + matchSet.size() + " matches");
        for(String match : matchSet){
            System.out.println("match:  " + match);
        }
    }

    public static Set<String> findMatches(List<String> searchList, Set<String> targetSet) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        Set<String> locatedMatchSet = new HashSet<String>();

        int threadCount = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();   

        List<List<String>> partitionList = getChunkList(searchList, threadCount);

        if(partitionList.size() == 1){
            //if we only have one "chunk" then don't bother with a thread-pool
            locatedMatchSet = new ListSearcher(searchList, targetSet).call();
        }else{  
            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
            CompletionService<Set<String>> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<Set<String>>(executor);

            for(List<String> chunkList : partitionList)
                completionService.submit(new ListSearcher(chunkList, targetSet));

            for(int x = 0; x < partitionList.size(); x++){
                Set<String> threadMatchSet = completionService.take().get();
                locatedMatchSet.addAll(threadMatchSet);
            }

            executor.shutdown();
        }


        return locatedMatchSet;
    }

    private static class ListSearcher implements Callable<Set<String>> {

        private final List<String> searchList;
        private final Set<String> targetSet;
        private final Set<String> matchSet = new HashSet<String>();

        public ListSearcher(List<String> searchList, Set<String> targetSet) {
            this.searchList = searchList;
            this.targetSet = targetSet;
        }

        @Override
        public Set<String> call() {
            for(String searchValue : searchList){
                if(targetSet.contains(searchValue))
                    matchSet.add(searchValue);
            }

            return matchSet;
        }

    }

    private static <T> List<List<T>> getChunkList(List<T> unpartitionedList, int splitCount) {
        int totalProblemSize = unpartitionedList.size();
        int chunkSize = (int) Math.ceil((double) totalProblemSize / splitCount);

        List<List<T>> chunkList = new ArrayList<List<T>>(splitCount);

        int offset = 0;
        int limit = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < splitCount; x++){
            limit = offset + chunkSize;
            if(limit > totalProblemSize)
                limit = totalProblemSize;
            List<T> subList = unpartitionedList.subList(offset, limit);
            chunkList.add(subList);
            offset = limit;
        }

        return chunkList;
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 looks good & I like the idea of using a completion service.

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely possible to parallelize this using multiple threads.  You could do the following:

1. Break up the list into a different "blocks," one per thread that will do the search.
2. Have each thread look over its block, checking whether each string is in the set, and if so adding the string to the resulting set.

For example, you might have the following thread routine:

```
public void scanAndAdd(List<String> allStrings, Set<String> toCheck,
                       ConcurrentSet<String> matches, int start, int end) {
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        if (toCheck.contains(allStrings.get(i))) {
            matches.add(allStrings.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

You could then spawn off as many threads as you needed to run the above method and wait for all of them to finish.  The resulting matches would then be stored in `matches`.

For simplicity, I've had the output set be a `ConcurrentSet`, which automatically eliminates race conditions due to writes.  Since you are only doing reads on the list of strings and set of strings to check for, no synchronization is required when reading from `allStrings` or performing lookups in `toCheck`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: "Since you are only doing reads on the list of strings and set of strings to check for, no synchronization is required". Wrong! You still need to publish it correctly.

Comment: @unbeli- Sorry - by that statement, I meant that no synchronization is required *during the reading*.  I assume that the list is not being concurrently populated by another thread.  I also did explicitly use a `ConcurrentMap` in order to produce the output list, which implicitly handles the concurrency.  Or am I missing something deeper here?

Answer (score 1):

Simply splitting *lines* among different threads would (in Oracle JVM at least) spread the work into all CPUs if you are looking for this.
I like using CyclicBarrier, makes those threads controlled in an easier way.

http://javarevisited.blogspot.cz/2012/07/cyclicbarrier-example-java-5-concurrency-tutorial.html

Comment: you would start as many threads as you would need, number of lines divided by number of CPUs plus one thread would be probably the best. CyclicBarrier would allow you to use them sequentially, to wait until their all done.

Comment: in case it isn't clear: start as many threads you need, number of available CPUs is the best np =Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(), take numThreadsNeeded = np +1. pass a cyclic barrier to all threads in their constructor and make them call await() on it after they're finished with their part of the job

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use [Akka](http://akka.io), it does these kinds of things quite simply.

Actually, having done some search work with Akka, one of the things I can tell you about this too is that it supports two ways of parallelizing such things: through Composable Futures or Agents. For what you want, the Composable Futures would be completely sufficient. Then, Akka is actually not adding that much: Netty is providing the massively parallel io infrastructure, and Futures are part of the jdk, but Akka does make it super simple to put these two together and extend them when/if needed.